# is it good way to call WCF service to get data for initializing controls like dropdowns and grids

Tags: database, wcf

I am new to WCF and trying to create a sample application.
I just wonder is it best practise to call Service methods to get data frequently.
For example, on the page load, for initializing controls like dropdowns, grids and text boxes with data from database, what would be the best way, calling WCF service or using ADO.net.

Please explain.

thank you

Comment: I feel its better to send the dropdowns pre-poulated, when you are sending the HTML itself. No need for 2 calls, one a GET for HTML, and on page load a GET for static data to WCF service, and javascript to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason why you consider a WCF service to retrieve those values ?

Is the data coming from an external party, or do you have the data in your database ?  If you have it in your DB, why do you consider making an WCF call (extra complexity, performance penalty) to retrieve those data ?

Answer (score 0):

WCF and ADO.NET are complete different technologies. You will use them for different scenarios.
WCF is used when creating scalable, distributed applications. ADO.NET is used as a database technology. They can be used together but they are certainly not interchangeable.

If your Web Server which is running your ASP.NET code has direct access to the database server, you can use ADO.NET to query your database and initialize some values when loading the page. You don't WCF for this scenario.

WCF is a technology that is used for communication between servers. Normally, you would use WCF to setup a web service that can be called from other applications. The WCF service would then execute some code (for example, it could use ADO.NET to access a database that's accessible from the WCF Server) and then return the results to the client. Using WCF will have a performance penalty. You should only use it when you are creating a distributed application or if you want to divide your workload over multiple servers.